# Haml nested blocks

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I am newbie in HAML. So what about this in HAML ?

```
    -if @link.is_active
      %a
    -else
       #custom-div
         .custom-class
```

So I want to see if some condition is true

```
    <a><div id = "custom-div"><div class = "custom-class"></div></div></a>
```

And if it's false:

```
    <div id = "custom-div"><div class = "custom-class"></div></div>
```

Without copying of blocks, I mean not this:

```
   -if @link.is_active
     %a
       #custom-div
         .custom-class
    -else
       #custom-div
         .custom-class
```

Any proposes ?

Comment: you can try using `surround` method of HAML

Comment: You can something like this `- surround(@link.is_active ? "%a" : "", @link.is_active ? "%a" : "") do          #custom-div
         .custom-class`

Comment: Ok, I will try, but what if I have some difficult logic with 1-2 eslifs and elses ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haml 4.1.0.beta.1 has a [`haml_tag_if` helper](https://github.com/haml/haml/commit/66a8ee080a9fb82907618227e88ce5c2c969e9d1). You can use it like this:

```
- haml_tag_if @link.is_active, :a do
  #custom-div
     .custom-class
```

If you can’t use 4.1.0 you could add the helper yourself, it is fairly simple. This should work:

```
def haml_tag_if(condition, *tag)
  if condition
    haml_tag(*tag){ yield }
  else
    yield
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how complicated `#custom-div .#custom-class` really is you could use `link_to_if`:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_if

```
= link_to_if @link.is_active, "html safe linkable text here", "url to link to"
```